# Update single column based on conditions

Tags: sql-server, database

How to update single column based on two or multiple conditions in SQL Server.
I have a table called `show_list` and it looks like this:

```
emp_id    to_date      show_flag
1         2019-01-01            
2         2019-01-01
3         2019-01-01
4         2019-01-01
```

I have to update `emp_id` 1 and 3 with `show_flag = 1` and `emp_id` 2 and 4 with `show_flag = 0`.

Comment: Please consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: Use case statement: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: Also, please show what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try:

```
update MyTable set show_flag = case when emp_id = 1 or emp_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end
```

or

```
update MyTable set show_flag = 1
where emp_id in (1, 3)
update MyTable set show_flag = 0
where emp_id in (2, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try it, odd and even emp_id.

```
UPDATE yourTable SET show_flag = CASE WHEN emp_id % 2 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if emp_id%2=0
begin
    UPDATE yourTable SET show_flag = 0
end
else
begin
   UPDATE yourTable SET show_flag = 1
end
```